# Select child of current node based on attribute value in XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have XML like

```
   ...
    <S head="X">
       <A head="X">
          <A1 head="Z">
          <A2 head="X">
       <B head="Y">
    </S>
   ...
```

I would like to select a child of `S` which has an attribute whose value is "X". (**Note I know nothing about the names of elements `S`, `A`, `B`...**)

I tried

```
string headTag = node.SelectSingleNode("//*[@head='X']").Name;
```

It returns "S", while I expect to get "A" if `node` points to `S` and "A2" if `node` points to `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XPath will select all of the child elements, regardless of name, with a `@head` attribute value equal to `X`:

```
./*[@head='X']
```

starting from the current node.

When the current node is `S`, it'll select `A`; when the current node is `A`, it'll select `A2`, all as requested.